# How to decide SPDX license for a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ethereumj

I am not sure how to decide which spdx licence will go with my smart contract. Can anyone help like how decide which spdx licence will be use in a contract.

Comment: This is not related to Ethereum. You should choose one that is best for your business or work. If it is something for learning perhaps an open source license will be best, the licenses ISC, MIT, GPL2 are commonly used, but there are many to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first learn about [software licensing and open-source licensing](https://snyk.io/learn/what-is-a-software-license/), and then decide which licence best fits your needs. Then, once decided:

1. Place it in your SPDX license field.
2. Place LICENSE file in your project directory containing the details of that license.